# How to test a target other than Release with Subliminal automated testing for IOS

Tags: ios, subliminal

We are building an IOS app that talks to a server backend. We have several possible servers (dev, stable, staging, prod) and have a Release target for each. We would like to run the subliminal-test script and select the proper target to test. Is it possible to select a target other than "Release"? Possibly with the -e option?

Answer (score 0):

`subliminal-test` builds the target specified by `-scheme`.

The scheme (which usually shares a name with its target) defaults to "Integration Tests", not "Release", so I feel like you might be talking about build configurations vs. targets. (`subliminal-test` does default to using the "Release" configuration.) If you'd like to change the configuration, you can do that using `-configuration`.

Here's some information about targets, schemes, and build configurations fwiw: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009328-CH4-SW1).